# Initializing component with parameter set from other page in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, cookies, react-hooks, next.js, local-storage

I have 2 components on separate pages in nextjs. The way I would like my app to work is:

1. User inputs some data on page A and clicks submit
2. A request to my backend is sent and it returns a 'accessToken', at the same time the user is redirected to page B
3. To load page B the 'accessToken' is sent to an external service to initialize the component provided by that service
4. If the user leaves the page and returns, the 'accessToken' should be still set and they should not need to re-do step 1,2 but if they request a new one then that should also be updated in page B

Below the component provided by the external service for reference:

```
<WebSdk
  accessToken={token}
  expirationHandler={handler}
  config={config}
  options={options}
  onMessage={messageHandler}
  onError={errorHandler}
/>
```

How should I store and read the access token? Do I need to use `useState` or `useEffect`? Do I need to set a cookie or localStorage?

Answer (score 1):

Neither `useState` nor `useEffect` is good choice for this condition.

You can use both `cookies(low security)` and `localStorage` , but I recommend using `sessionStorage(it has expire time)` .I

Comment: Would I need to utilize `useEffect` to read sessionStorage in page B?

Comment: Also, what makes useState a bad choice for this? The fact I want the state to persist when the user leaves the page?

Comment: 1-yes you can use `useEffect` for reading data. 2-The state gets refreshed while you are routing

Comment: Can I not do this https://reactician.com/articles/sharing-state-between-nextjs-page-navigations-using-react-contexts to share state between nextjs pages?

Comment: yes you can do that and drill your props , but `sessionStorage` and `localStorage` are the best choices.